# tokens must be a non-empty array at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**I can't figure out the issue why my tokens list remains empty!**
I have a collection of users with a field of role to each document. I am iterating over those documents, to check which document field role is equal to shipper in order to retrieve token. So that I could sendMulticast notifications to each shipper device.
My order snapshot also contains the shipper tokens as well I am iterating over users collections to grab token for pushing into the list but both of them aren't pushing data into list.
*Here's my cloud function code:*

```
exports.notifyShipper= functions.firestore.document('/orders/{documentId}')
.onCreate(async (snap,context) => {
    functions.logger.log('Sending Notifications to the shippers');

    var shipperTokens=[];

    await admin.firestore().collection("users").get().then(snapshot => {

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
       if(doc.role =='shipper'){
         shipperTokens.push(doc.token);
         functions.logger.log(doc.token);
       }
    });

  });
  Array.prototype.push.apply(shipperTokens, snap.shipperTokens);
  functions.logger.log(snap.shipperTokens.toString());

  //   const tokensOfShippers = [
  //   'd7M5eixYQYCmXgDx1rOmKc:APA91bHUELrCtEIHHcoQnQ9p5SqqpeZbKpUe60OyGPlZ4GZ9cm5wosfTZFoHV7NcDm2-5Sowpck2YCIkpzZ7ku3u6LSk9tODHA54OrawxNvOQqlK-x7W6VE4wsAS5KCtK4JPtg2nRfCg',
  //  'cBPUl8FzTJaQx8Mg_CkPbv:APA91bG0bZu7lD8EAxExTqcnJfZjpl71YdtfjdugwREGo-sO8URbjJILRc_DHY61wKJlnYGWCjbKdieKpvPJd5rtaPYa6rBHo1JQqiToVGs4WGd-2D3Y-bMVIzzU8TIzR772oTAUiyR7',
  //  'cuJAUqqCRKq77UsbBS6kZD:APA91bEDWjSR4z9yUSfFg-FpOPMA3VXsyjJ613Etv5MhpV31nsSP5hhgumWmsoLKGh1_TbP3yd9KDU7vO4DYqW5mJpSjPKzllBuw7I-lEAY6UYasJKQXv9DZt82agPyr7oac-JBC_XMr',
  //  'erYeroRkRM-s9y70l8cFqd:APA91bGzT_nT-kWUBXTBX-aDtN8Ew5ypDpbDFWcQw6O5zo4jFQFnMy2_E4Lt5GYVJXcaudK8u7LhkoQadjlfmxtG9jhIhCCch2o850UJcCqrCiNz7muBwKcp0E-y3MrHz9iAAJZ_4uJ3'
  //   ];
    await admin.messaging().sendMulticast({
         tokens : shipperTokens,
          notification: {
              title: "Hi TELLOO Shipper",
             body: "We recieved an order, please have a look on the dashboard!",
               imageUrl: "https://en.pimg.jp/040/171/400/1/40171400.jpg",
        }
   });
});
```

This is the complete error that I'm facing in logs:

```
Error: tokens must be a non-empty array
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:279:16)
    at Messaging.sendMulticast (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:301:19)
    at /workspace/index.js:391:53
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Did you check if this logs anything? `functions.logger.log(doc.token);`

Comment: No. This logs nothing. I can't find proper help or tutorials in docs of firebase(updated ones) that how to communicate with firestore using cloud function in flutter. Will this line of code would get the shipper docs properly? `await admin.firestore().collection("users").get().then(snapshot => {

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Firebase documentation on [reading multiple documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection), you'll see that it uses the `data()` function on each `DocumentSnapshot` to get at the fields of that document.

So your `doc.role` and `doc.token` should instead of `doc.data().role` and `doc.data().token`.